# Unable to share PDF file using share sheet Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a PDF using vision kit and share it using the share sheet.
Once the PDF is created the share sheet shows up and brings up the options but when I proceed to click on one of the items it gives me an error saying "This item cannot be shared. Please select a different item."

I cannot find any discrepancies in the code or the terminal at the moment.

Here's the code used to create and share the PDF:

```
   
        func createNewPDF(arrImage: [UIImage]) -> Data? {
            
            let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
            for i in 0...arrImage.count-1 {
                let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: arrImage[i])
                pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage!, at: i)
            }
            let pdfData = pdfDocument.dataRepresentation()
            
            

            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).map(\.path)
            let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
            let fullPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("\(pdfnameing).pdf") as URL
            let fullPathf = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("\(pdfnameing).pdf").path
            let urll = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("\(pdfnameing).pdf") as NSURL
            do {
                   let data = try Data(contentsOf: fullPath)

                   try data.write(to: urll as URL)

                   let activitycontroller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [urll], applicationActivities: nil)
                   if activitycontroller.responds(to: #selector(getter: activitycontroller.completionWithItemsHandler))
                   {
                       activitycontroller.completionWithItemsHandler = {(type, isCompleted, items, error) in
                           if isCompleted
                           {
                               print("completed")
                           }
                       }
                   }
                
                if let popoverController = activitycontroller.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverController.sourceView = self.view
                  popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
                  popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []

              }
                   activitycontroller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
                   self.present(activitycontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)

               }
               catch {
                   //ERROR
               }
            

           let activityItems = [tempURL]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

     if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
           popoverController.sourceView = self.view
          popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
       popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []

  }

   self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            
            return pdfData
        }
```

> 'pdfnameing' is a string used to name the PDF file

[image: Here's a picture of the Error]

Thanks for the help in advance!

**EDIT:**
After the changes were recommended, I still got the same error as shown in the picture above.

The code with the changes:

```
        
        func createNewPDF(arrImage: [UIImage]) -> Data? {
            
            let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
            for i in 0...arrImage.count-1 {
                let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: arrImage[i])
                pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage!, at: i)
            }
            let pdfData = pdfDocument.dataRepresentation()
            let tempURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
                .appendingPathComponent("\(pdfnameing).pdf")
            do {
         

                   let activitycontroller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [tempURL], applicationActivities: nil)
                   if activitycontroller.responds(to: #selector(getter: activitycontroller.completionWithItemsHandler))
                   {
                       activitycontroller.completionWithItemsHandler = {(type, isCompleted, items, error) in
                           if isCompleted
                           {
                               print("completed")
                           }
                       }
                   }

                if let popoverController = activitycontroller.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverController.sourceView = self.view
                  popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
                  popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []

              }
                   activitycontroller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
                   self.present(activitycontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)

               }
               catch {
                   //ERROR
               }
            
      let anURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempURL)

           let activityItems = [anURL]
            
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

     if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
           popoverController.sourceView = self.view
          popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
       popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []

  }

   self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)



            return pdfData
        }
```

Debugger Log:

```
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2020-11-03 15:57:48.058158+0530 Scan Box[4068:1060013] [] Trying to load recrop for scan, but the quad is nil, setting starting UI recrop to a 95% unit rect
Success
2020-11-03 15:58:10.127405+0530 Scan Box[4068:1060013] [core] SLRemoteComposeViewController: (this may be harmless) viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have never saved the pdfData. There is a lot of non sense code where you try to load the data from the disk but you already have the data in your pdfData variable.

Just remove those lines

```
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).map(\.path)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let fullPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("\(pdfnameing).pdf") as URL
let fullPathf = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("\(pdfnameing).pdf").path
let urll = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("\(pdfnameing).pdf") as NSURL
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fullPath)
    try data.write(to: urll as URL)
```

---

and replace it with:

```
let pdfData = pdfDocument.dataRepresentation()
let tempURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
    .appendingPathComponent("\(pdfnameing).pdf")
do {
    try pdfData.write(to: tempURL)
```

Comment: I have made the edits. Please have a look and thanks for the help!

Comment: No wonder it did not work. You did not remove this line `let data = try Data(contentsOf: tempURL)`

Comment: I removed the lines but it still doesn't work.... I added breakpoints but I found out that it doesn't run anything inside the 'do' brackets, and only runs the code after 'catch' which gives me the error shown in the image above....

Comment: try printing `Array(pdfData)`